# IBM Process Center didn't get installed while installing Process Server

Tags: designer, business-process-management

I have installed IBM Process Server but there is no Process Center installed. I need to download Process Designer once Process Center is in place. But for some reasons I am unable to find Process Center. I tried to create a profile from a response file but that is failing. I guess while creating the process center profile all the artifacts like DB2 databases, etc will be installed. I don't know how to explain but if my question is understood then please do help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

IID install media contains a cut down version of the IBM Process Manager Advanced server runtime. This runtime can create a Process Server profile only. There is no way to create a Process Center profile. This seems rather odd, since, Process Center is something that is used mainly in the development world. If you must use Process Center from IID, take these steps:

```
Install IID without any test environment.
Install IBM Process Manager and choose to create a Process Center profile at the time of installation. This is the quickest way to create a fully functional server runtime.
From IID, create a server of type IBM Process Server v7.5. Point to the directory where IBM Process Manager was installed (C:\IBM\BPM\v7.5 by default).
```

Courtesy of Bibhas Bhattacharya
URL: http://blog.webagesolutions.com/archives/447